# cordova plugin twilio_client_phonegap in hosted webapp : cordova

Tags: cordova, twilio, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

I am using [this plugin](https://github.com/jefflinwood/twilio_client_phonegap) in my cordova app to use twilio client sdk functionality. Plugin is working fine in my app.

**Question**

I needed this plugin in my "Hosted Cordova App", this plugin uses tcplugin.js and i cannot find help to use this plugin in my app.

*I dont think including .js file manually will work.

Any help or reference will be appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I have used cordova-plugin-remote-injection to inject the plugins in hosted app. 
Copy and paste the tcplugin.js and load it on device ready, it will work.